# Publishing asp.net c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, guys can anyone assist me. My project runs fine locally but it shows the below error when I click on something while I'm running the app in the published version.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path 
was not found

Source Error:
```

Comment: Consider debugging it. There is an exception, there are not enough details. Use a log file, event log, find the exception there. Obviously you skip info (the network path) and have bad code (using an invalid network path).

Comment: Check your web.config or some configuration files to see if you have something pointing to localhost.